# Must accuracy increase after every epoch?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

When training a neural neural network using batches, should accuracy (training and validation) increase after every epoch (after seeing the whole data an additional time)?

I want to be able to quickly judge if the network settings (learning rate, number of nodes.. etc) is reasonable. It also seemed necessary that the more the whole dataset is seen, the better the performance should be.

So, if the performance decreases at an epoch, should I be worried that something is wrong (high learning rate, high bias)? (Or do I always have to wait several epochs to judge?)

Answer (score 2):

I would say it depends on dataset and architecture. Hence, fluctuations are normal, but in general loss should improve. You can have a look at these practical guides to better interpret loss curves:

http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-3/#loss

https://blog.slavv.com/37-reasons-why-your-neural-network-is-not-working-4020854bd607

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in a perfect world one would expect the test accuracy to increase. If the test accuracy starts to decrease it might be that your network is overfitting. You might want to stop the learning just before you reach that point or take other steps to counter the overfitting problem.

Also, it could be a result of noise in the test dataset, i.e. wrongly labeled examples.